# Float to String with optional decimal point

Tags: haskell, numeric

I expect the following code to output `123`, [but instead it prints `123.0`](http://ideone.com/cAVqa1).

```
import Numeric
main = putStrLn $ showFFloat Nothing 123 ""
```

Is `showFFloat` broken, or do I misread the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFFloat)?

I would expect this behavior only from [showFFloatAlt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFFloatAlt).

Comment: I find it hard to tell whether "full precision" of a floating point is intended to include `.0` or not. I'd think it should omit that, as you assumed.

Comment: I'd expect the `0.` only from [showFFloatAlt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Numeric.html#v:showFFloatAlt). Added this remark to my question.

Comment: What does the documentation mean by "full precision" ? It refers to that term several times in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect that result. 'Full precision' seems to include 'minimum uncertancy'. From `123`, one cannot know if it has been rounded, from `123.0` one can. Using `Just 0` instead of `Nothing` should conform to your expectations.

Comment: Yes, using `Just 0` results in `"42"`, but that is not an optimal solution for cases like `42.34`. Additionally there should be a difference between `showFFloat` and `showFFloatAlt`.

Comment: It probably does. The ``Alt`` versions only difference is to guarantee the presence of the decimal point, even if not needed. While this might imply that values exists, for which `showFFloat` ommits the decimal point, it does not imply that it always ommits it when possible. Although I second you on that being a sensible guarantee that should be included. Thus, the function is not broken, rather insensibly defined:)

Comment: OK, thanks. So I will have to use something along these lines: http://ideone.com/7x3clc